# Intersection of two quadrics that have a common inscribed sphere

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

This is related to a question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200952/intersection-of-cones-tangent-to-a-common-sphere) on math.stackexchange. It didn't receive an answer there (except for my answer), and my question here is a generalization of that one, anyway.

Suppose I have two quadric surfaces $Q1$ and $Q2$ in plain ordinary 3D space, $\mathbb{R}^3$, and they have a common inscribed tangent sphere $S$, as shown in the picture. 
[image]

In general, the intersection of two quadric surfaces is a nasty curve of degree 4. But in our case, because of the common tangency, I suspect that **the intersection of $Q1$ and $Q2$ is just a pair of ellipses**. Numerical experiments seem to suggest this, anyway. My question: is my conjecture true, and, if so, what is the proof?

My tags might well be wrong, so please feel free to edit.

Comment: The curve of degree 4 is what is called a "quartic elliptic normal curve".  One important invariant of such an curve is what is the "arithmetic genus".  For a quartic elliptic normal curve, the arithmetic genus equals 1 (by "adjunction").  However, the two tangency points to the inscribed sphere impose two "nodes" on the quartic elliptic normal curve.  Every node decreases by 1 the "geometric genus" of the curve.  In particular, except for very degenerate configurations (where one of your quadrics is a "double plane"), this forces the curve to be a disjoint union of two plane conics.

Comment: Typo correction: "... what is the ..." --> " ... what is called the ..."

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what a "node" is, and it's not clear how the tangency with the sphere affects the quadric-quadric intersection. The tangency and the intersection seem like separate things, to me. Can you expand your answer, please, or Is there somewhere that I can read about arithmetic genus, geometric genus, nodes, etc.

Comment: But, anyway, you are saying that my conjecture is true, right? Is this a well-known result?

Comment: This is not a conjecture.  It is a computation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a nice observation about quadrics, I haven't seen it stated anywhere. It can be proved with the help of pencils of quadrics.

1) *The curve of tangency is a circle.*

Consider the pencil of quadrics spanned by $S$ and $Q_1$ (the set of quadrics whose equations are linear combinations of those for $S$ and $Q_1$). All quadrics of the pencil are tangent along the same curve, and somewhere in the pencil there is a degenerate quadric, which is a cylinder or a cone.

2) *The quadric $Q_1$ can be described by an equation of the form*
$$\|x\|^2 -r^2 + c_1 f_1^2 = 0,$$
where $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

Indeed, the pencil through $S$ and $Q_1$ contains the double plane through the circle of tangency. Let $f_1 = 0$ be the equation of this plane. The quadric $Q_1$ can be described by a linear combination of the equations for $S$ and the equation $f_1^2 = 0$ of the double plane.

Similarly, $Q_2$ has an equation of the form
$$\|x\|^2 - r^2 + c_2f_2^2=0.$$
Take the difference of the above equations. The intersection of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is contained in the union of two planes $\sqrt{c_1}f_1 \pm \sqrt{c_2}f_2 = 0$. Each of these planes intersects $Q_i$ along a conic.

Comment: Crystal clear, and written in nice simple terms that even I can understand. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there is a far more general result. In Salmon's "Analytic Geometry of Three Dimensions", 4th edition, page 117, we find the following:

> Two quadrics having plane contact with the same third quadric intersect each other in plane curves.  Proof: Obviously $U-L^2$ and $U-M^2$ have the planes $L-M$ and $L+M$ for their planes of intersection.

This is essentially the same proof given in Ivan's answer.